# use constant instead of string array in config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-config

```
string[] sectionGroupNames = new string[] { "commonSwitches", "tfsSwitches", "customConfigurationSwitches", "QuiteModeSwitches" };
```

Instead of this I need to use constants to apply configuration settings in `app.config` file

App.config File :

```
<sectionGroup name="commonSwitches">
 <section name="switchDefinitions" type="System.Configuration.DefaultSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> 
</sectionGroup> 
<sectionGroup name="tfsSwitches">
 <section name="switchDefinitions" type="System.Configuration.DefaultSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
 </sectionGroup>
 <sectionGroup name="customConfigurationSwitches">
 <section name="switchDefinitions" type="System.Configuration.DefaultSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
 </sectionGroup> 
<sectionGroup name="QuiteModeSwitches"> 
<section name="switchDefinitions" type="System.Configuration.DefaultSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> 
</sectionGroup>
```

---

How to do that?

Comment: instead of defining in .config file, create a separate xml / Json file and store the data. After that you can write code to read from that xml/json file.

Answer (score 0):

If not complicate the things, you could just have all your values as one string in App.config that you just split in the code:

**App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
        <appSettings>
            <add key="sectionGroupNames" value="commonSwitches, tfsSwitches, customConfigurationSwitches, QuiteModeSwitches"/>
        </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Program:**

```
string[] sectionGroupNames = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sectionGroupNames"].Split(new [] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```